# Load sound problem in OpenAL

Tags: openal, tao

I have problem loading a sound with OpenAL:

```
// in SoundManager.cs
public void LoadSound(string soundId, string path)
        {
            // Generate a buffer.
            int buffer = -1;
            Al.alGenBuffers(1, out buffer);
            int errorCode = Al.alGetError();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(errorCode == Al.AL_NO_ERROR);
            int format;
            float frequency;
            int size;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(File.Exists(path));
            IntPtr data = Alut.alutLoadMemoryFromFile(path, out format, out size,
            out frequency);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(data != IntPtr.Zero, "Problem");
            // Load wav data into the generated buffer.
            Al.alBufferData(buffer, format, data, size, (int)frequency);
            // Everything seems ok, add it to the library.
            _soundIdentifier.Add(soundId, new SoundSource(buffer, path));
        }

// Form.cs
 private void InitializeSounds()
        {            
            _soundManager.LoadSound("effect", "soundA.wav");            
        }
```

1. soundIdentifier is a Dictionary, in SoundSource i keep information for a sound, and the first string is a normal name for the sound like "cow", "horse", or whatever.
2. I call InitializeSounds from Form.cs and LoadSound is method for a sound manager.
3. Alut.alutLoadMemoryFromFile causes the error, for some reason returns a null pointer.
4. The rest is simple code hope you can understand.

I work in c# with Tao.OpenAL.

Comment: I used Alut.alutGetError() and I get error 519. How do I now convert that to some enum? I cant find what that error means

Comment: I figured out the error, it is :

"There was an error opening the ALC device"

What should I look for to fix this?

Comment: used the OpenAL Installer for Windows from http://connect.creativelabs.com/openal/Downloads/Forms/AllItems.aspx and it fixed this for me

Comment: You may have already figured this out.  But for those coming here while reading c# game programming.  see this wiki.http://wiki-guide.org/wiki/Windows_Error/?kw=alut%20error%20519

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-install open al.  Go here to re-install.

http://connect.creativelabs.com/openal/Downloads/Forms/AllItems.aspx